# JavaScript - Get values of non-predefined keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I've an array of objects and I'm trying to get the values of it, although the variables inside are not predefined. The problem is that I don't know how to do that.

**Array:**

```
Array[3]: [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "name1",
        lastname: "lastname1"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "name2",
        lastname: "lastname2"
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        name: "name3",
        lastname: "lastname3"
    }
]
```

**Javascript:**

```
this.myFunction = function(response) {
    var iLength = response.data.length;

    for(var i=0;i<iLength;i++) {
        var jLength = Object.keys(response.data[i]).length;

        for(var j=0;j<jLength;j++) {
            // ???
        }
    }
}
```

So instead of accessing the values this way,

```
response.data[i].id
response.data[i].name
response.data[i].lastname
```

I would rather access it in this way:

```
response.data[i]."somethingSomething[j]";
```

Is that possible? I'm fairly new to AngularJS, so I might be approaching this matter not in right way. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit: I have formulated my question better.**

Comment: may i know what is your final required output,do u want to store them in something or do u want to display them some where/?

Comment: Try `response.data[i][somethingSomething[j]]` instead of `response.data[i].somethingSomething[j]`. Is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Comment: I want to store the results inside another object. I actually don't know how to call the values inside response.data. I'm looking for something like "response.data[i].value[j]" or "response.data[i].text[j]".

Comment: what do you mean by 'array accessed dynamically' ? When using square brackets and indices it is accessed (dynamically). You can use a name on an object keys... It's not for arrays, which are lists basically... Be more precise.

Comment: I needed a way to iterate through my array without knowing the keys inside my objects in advance. @Nina Scholz answer helped me to solve the problem. I should have been more precisely with my questions. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate over the keys.

```
for (var i = 0; i < iLength; i++) {
    var keys = Object.keys(response.data[i]);

    for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
        console.log(response.data[i][keys[j]]);
    }
}
```

But if you know the keys in advance, you could use an array with the keys and maintain a stable order while iterating.

```
var keys = ['id', 'name', 'lastname'];
for (var i = 0; i < iLength; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
        console.log(response.data[i][keys[j]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for, since I don't know the keys in advance. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ArturD. there's one way to say "thank you" is giving green tick to this answers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for ... in ...` like this :

```js
var obj = {
  id: "1",
  name: "name1",
  lastname: "lastname1"
};

for (key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
    document.body.innerHTML += key + "<br>";
}
```